# go mod fails to find version v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 of a dependency

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, go-modules

I'm trying to download all of the dependencies of a project via go mod; the problem occurs when it comes to execute `go mod vendor` on the CLI. The output is as follows:

```
go: finding github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
go: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: unknown revision 000000000000
go: error loading module requirements
```

The code that imports the libraries is this:

```golang
import (    
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/ledger"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/resmgmt"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabsdk"
)
```

krakengosdk is the name of the package I'm working on:

```
go mod init krakengosdk
```

Any solution? I've been looking for any solution for a while, but I haven't came across anything useful.

EDIT: I've updated the go version to 1.13; it seems like the error has to be with "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/test/integration@v0.0.0-20190918153951-5d7ae7a5be8f":

```
go get -v github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/test/integration@latest
go: finding github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/test/integration latest
go get: github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/test/integration@v0.0.0-20190918153951-5d7ae7a5be8f requires
    github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: invalid version: unknown revision 000000000000
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Proposed diagnostics

I suggest to try those commands in console (bash/dash/fish/zsh):

```sh
# 1. Create clean project 
$ mkdir /tmp/checkmods && cd /tmp/checkmods  # create clean directory
$ export GO111MODULES=on
$ go version # check that version 1.13
$ go mod init main # name of package does not matter here

# 2. Install packages, check output
$ go get -v github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/ledger
$ go get -v github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/resmgmt
$ go get -v github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabsdk

# 3. Create main.go 
$ touch main.go
$ # edit main.go, add imported packages, import something from those packages
$ go mod vendor 
# Do you have problems here? 
# if you encounter problems: 
# - play around  with `go mod tidy`
# - look at `go.mod` and `go.sum`
# - `go mod graph/verify/why` - are your friends
```

Example of `main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/ledger"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/resmgmt"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/fabsdk"
)

func main() {
    var (
        cln  &ledger.Client
        rsm  &resmgmt.Client
        fbs  &fabsdk.FabricSDK
    )
    fmt.Printf("%T %T %T\n", cln, rsm, fbs)
}
```

### Analysis

If you encounter problems: explain on which line you encountered, what kind of problem.

If everything OK with clean start: look what is different between your project and clean start (diffs for go.sum & go.mod)

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Questions:

1. What is your exact go.mod file?
2. Do you have any `replace` directives for `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go`?
3. If you don't currently, did you at one time?

That long version `v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000` is what usually shows up if you have a `replace` directive but don't have a corresponding `require` directive and the `go` command automatically adds a `require` directive for you using that long version.

That can be fine, but I wonder if you did something like added a `replace`, but then later removed the `replace` while leaving in place the long version `v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000` in the `require`. Or something like that.

What happens if you:

1. Remove any `replace` directives for `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go` that you might have
2. Change the `require` for `github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go` to be:

```
 require github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go latest
```

3. Run `go list -m all`

Also, if not already, you should be using the latest release of Go 1.13, which fixes some bugs but also often has much better error messages.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me because of using replace flag and removing the replace flag. This can be corrected with use of below two commands.

```
go mod edit -droprequire=github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go
```

Above command drops the dependency

```
go mod tidy
```

Above command re-downloads the dependency.

Comment: Please make sure to use correct package name for as per your error.

Answer (score 2):

**Error** - the version that go is trying to pull for that specific module that imports it is either outdated or invalid.

**Solution** - For example in my case i was getting this error below:

```
go: downloading github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/books imports
    github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/books/server imports
    github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books: github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: invalid version: unknown revision 000000000000
```

as you can see above my module "github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/books/server" imports another module "github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books:" this import throws the error above,  so i go to my go.mod file and make the following changes:

```
 1 module github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/books/server                                                                                                           
  2 
  3 go 1.18
  4 
  5 replace github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/db => ../../db
  6 
  7 replace github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books => ../../gen/go/proto/books
  8 
  9 require (
 10   github.com/arangodb/go-driver v1.3.2
 11   github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/db v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
 12   github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books latest
 13   google.golang.org/grpc v1.47.0
 14 )
```

check above in line 12 where i put **"latest"** instead of the version number i.e  "v0.0.0...."

I save the file and then i run  **"go mod tidy"**

The compiler then changes the "latest" designation to an up to date version,i.e it will look as below after running the mod tidy command.

```
1 module github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/books/server                                                                                                           
  2 
  3 go 1.18
  4 
  5 replace github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/db => ../../db
  6 
  7 replace github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books => ../../gen/go/proto/books
  8 
  9 require (
 10   github.com/arangodb/go-driver v1.3.2
 11   github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/db v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
 12   github.com/myk4040okothogodo/tutorial/gen/go/proto/books v0.0.0-20220601171028-60237b9c9583
 13   google.golang.org/grpc v1.47.0
 14 )
```

PS: check the package where i make the changes, dont change the wrong imports

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solution would work for everyone, but I just did `go get PACKAGE_WITH_ISSUE`, so in your case:

```
go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go
```